# Search files from various sites and list them

Tags: c#, asp.net, mp3, search-engine

I want to create a file search engine for educational purposes. But i dont know how. Can you point me in the right direction please? Im aware of screen scrapping and apis. I use asp.net & c# for programming.

As an example, how does [this  search engine](http://mp3.php-search-engine.com/index.php?search=metallica&source=All) search kohit.net and ectract the links. Kohit does not provide API or use parameters in url.

Comment: and mp3 search engine for educational purposes?

Comment: Yes. mp3 or any file search engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example I would say that

1. Either you get an API from each of the search engines you want to scan and use that API to execute searches on them using your search terms and displaying the results
2. Or if there's no way to use API you can access their search url with the search terms inserted there (like `http://search.ie/search.php?search=search+terms`) and parse the result, create your list of results and display it to the user. This is the least favorite of the two methods as it is most likely to fail with any restructuring of the target search engines' code

Comment: I want to search individual sites.

Comment: yes, for each individual site you need to either get the API (probably not available) or use the second method (probably not desirable)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool such as http://www.searchblox.com/ it provides built-in scraping mechanisms and indexing using Apache Lucene/Solr. The integration into ASP.NET is also quite simple using its RESTful API.

If you want to build a solution from scratch, you might need to consider a spidering tool and writing to a search platform such as Lucene/Solr or Sphinx and query them from your app. To query Solr from ASP.NET is simple using [SolrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/).